# Why i cannot get a numerical result?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have tried following code:

```
Limit[((sinx)^6)/(cosx - e^(-(x^(2))/2) + (x^(4))/12), x -> 0]
```

Following is the image representing what I have tried to implement:

[image]

The result I keep getting does not agree with me:

```
Out[3] = sinx^6/(-1 + cosx)
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: LJ Wei welcome to Mathematica SE! The reason why your code produces the result you don't agree with is due to the way you've written your code. There is a number of syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Capitals matter in Mathematica. Any function defined in MAthematica starts with Capital letter. For eg: Sin, Cos, etc. not sin, cos. When you type the function if it is valid it turns black otherwise it remains blue as in your case.

Answer (score 2):

```
Limit[Sin[x]^6/(Cos[x] - E^(-x^2/2) + x^4/12), x -> 0]
```

(* 360/7 *)